# Removing the recording icon MediaStreamRecorder.js library?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, mediastream

I am using the MediaStreamRecorder.js library for audio capture with Javascript. Almost everything is ok. The only problem I am finding is that when I click on Stop to stop recording the red recording icon is still up there, on the tab.
Anyone know how I remove this icon when you click Stop?

Example in jsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/davidsadan/wazb1jks

Here is the print of how it is when I click Stop:

[image]

ps: It only works with https, Sorry my english, im brazilian...

```js
var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true
};

var mediaRecorder;
var blobURL;
function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
 $(function(){


 mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);    
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/wav';
    mediaRecorder.audioChannels = 1;
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
        // POST/PUT "Blob" using FormData/XHR2
        blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $("#result").append('<audio controls src="' + blobURL + '"></audio><br><a href="' + blobURL + '" target="_blank">' + blobURL + '</a>');
    };
    mediaRecorder.start(5000*5000);
    setTimeout(function(){
     mediaRecorder.stop();
    }, 120 * 1000);//Se não clicar em parar, a gravação para automaticamente em 2 minutos.

    });
}

function onMediaError(e) {
    console.error('media error', e);
}

function onStop(){
 mediaRecorder.stop();
 mediaRecorder.stream.stop();
}

var interval;
function contadorIncremento(){
  var count = 1;
  interval = setInterval(function() { 
      if(count > 1)
        $('.contador').html("setInterval: Ja passou "+ count++ +" segundos!");
      else
        $('.contador').html("setInterval: Ja passou "+ count++ +" segundo!");
     }, 1000);
}

function stopContadorIncremento(){
    clearTimeout(interval);
    $('.contador').html("");
}

$(function(){
  
 $(".play").on("click", function(){ 
    navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
       contadorIncremento();

   });

   $(".stop").on("click", function(){
    mediaRecorder.stop();
      stopContadorIncremento();
   });

   $(".resume").on("click", function(){
    mediaRecorder.resume();
   });

   $(".salvar").on("click", function(){
    mediaRecorder.save();
   });

 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://webrtcexperiment-webrtc.netdna-ssl.com/MediaStreamRecorder.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="result"></div> 
<button class="play">Start</button>
<button class="stop">Stop</button>
<button class="resume">Resume</button>
<button class="salvar">Salvar</button>
  
 <div class="contador"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove red icon after recording has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670677/remove-red-icon-after-recording-has-stopped)

Answer (score 7):

You must aware that the red recording point is launched by the `getUserMedia` method. That method starts capturing the webcam or microphone as in your case (audio-only).

What happens with your code, is that you stops the recording feature, `mediaRecorder.stop()` but you are not stopping the capturing request.

So keep the reference to the track that you want to stop and stop it on demand.

```
var localStream;
// ...keep track onSuccess
function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    localStream = stream;
    // ...
}

// ...close it when requested (TIP: add req status variables)
$(".stop").on("click", function(){
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    localStream.stop();
```

Hope this helps!

**EDITED**

Due a dreprecation of the stream.stop() function, what you need to do is to select the specific track and stop it.

> There are three MediaStream deprecations in Chrome 45:
>
> ```
> MediaStream.ended
> MediaStream.label
> MediaStream.stop()
> ```
>
> In parallel are two additions:
>
> ```
> MediaStream.active
> MediaStreamTrack.stop()
> ```

So to stop it, first get these tracks (you should have only one).

```
// ...close it when requested (TIP: add req status variables)
$(".stop").on("click", function(){
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    // can also use getAudioTracks() or getVideoTracks()
    var track = localStream.getTracks()[0];  // if only one media track
    // ...
    track.stop();
});
```

Check more info about this upgrade and related resources here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/mediastream-deprecations?hl=en#stop-ended-and-active

Comment: I added an edition including an important change on Chrome 45, sorry. Hope this new option helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this..

```js
var tracks = localStream.getTracks();
    tracks.forEach(function(track){
      track.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true
};

var mediaRecorder;
var blobURL;
function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    $(function(){


    mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);    
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/wav';
    mediaRecorder.audioChannels = 1;
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
        // POST/PUT "Blob" using FormData/XHR2
        blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $("#result").append('<audio controls src="' + blobURL + '"></audio><br><a href="' + blobURL + '" target="_blank">' + blobURL + '</a>');
    };
    mediaRecorder.start(5000*5000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        mediaRecorder.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }, 120 * 1000);//Se não clicar em parar, a gravação para automaticamente em 2 minutos.

    });
}

function onMediaError(e) {
    console.error('media error', e);
}

function onStop(){
    mediaRecorder.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    mediaRecorder.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
}

var interval;
function contadorIncremento(){
  var count = 1;
  interval = setInterval(function() { 
      if(count > 1)
        $('.contador').html("setInterval: Ja passou "+ count++ +" segundos!");
      else
        $('.contador').html("setInterval: Ja passou "+ count++ +" segundo!");
     }, 1000);
}

function stopContadorIncremento(){
    clearTimeout(interval);
    $('.contador').html("");
}

$(function(){

    $(".play").on("click", function(){ 
        navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);
       contadorIncremento();

    });

    $(".stop").on("click", function(){
        mediaRecorder.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      stopContadorIncremento();
    });

    $(".resume").on("click", function(){
        mediaRecorder.resume();
    });

    $(".salvar").on("click", function(){
        mediaRecorder.save();
    });



});
```