# How to remove recording icon, after clicking stop button?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc, html5-audio

Recording has been started using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(). Following is the code: (Vue Js)

```
   <a href="javascript:void(null)" @click="stopRecording">Stop</a>
   <script>
    methods:{
     stopRecording() {
       if (window.mediaStream) {
         window.mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
         track.stop();
       });
      }
     }
    </script>
```

Also tried [Stop/Close webcam which is opened by navigator.getUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642926/stop-close-webcam-which-is-opened-by-navigator-getusermedia).
Immediately after calling track.stop(), the 'readyState' of audio is set to ended. But the recording icon is not removed from the tab.

Comment: The code shown is correct, and should be sufficient.  Which browser? - I suspect you have a bug in code not shown.

Comment: @jib I'm currently testing on chrome. Modified the question to whole code. I'm trying it on Vue Js. Hope this code works for all frameworks.

Comment: @jib There was a problem with my code. I was calling 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia' function 2 times and that caused the issue.
Thank you for your response. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove red icon after recording has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670677/remove-red-icon-after-recording-has-stopped)